# Mongoose validation for document retrieved from database

Tags: mongoose

User schema has two fields:

```
const userSchema = new m.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  nickname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false
  }
});
```

When I create a document manually and set "nickname" to undefined, there is a validation error. But when I select a user document from database, validation gives no error, although the "nickname" field is undefined. Why?

Here is the whole app:

```
const m = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new m.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  nickname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false
  }
});
const User = m.model("User", userSchema);

async function addUser() {
  const user = new User({
    name: "John",
    nickname: "Johnny"
  });
  try {
    await user.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err", err);
  }
}

async function checkUser() {
  const user1 = await User.findOne({ name: "John" });
  const user2 = new User({
    name: "John",
    nickname: undefined
  });

  const errors1 = user1.validateSync();
  console.log(errors1);
  const errors2 = user2.validateSync();
  console.log(errors2);
}

m.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(async () => {
  console.log("MongoDb connection successfull");
  await addUser();
  await checkUser();
  console.log("finished");
});
```

Comment: Because `typeof undefined === "undefined"` and `typeof "undefined" === "string"`?

Comment: As I know mongoose doesn't have validation for read methods. Why is this a problem if you validate your date when creating it? You ask just for curiosity?

Comment: Yes it's out of curiosity. If a field is required and it's value is undefined then the document should not validate. Unless e.g. validation is not run on documents (fields?) which are read from db and not changed. But I can't find such rule in documentation.